how to solve the mail reader sampler error in jmeter?
when i am trying to read the mail by using the mail reader sampler with both POP and IMAPS i am getting this type of error. here i have used the Gmail application i have tried all the security features but i am getting this type of error how can i solve this error using JMeter and i have to read the latest email in the Gmail using JMeter

now it is showing this type of error. after using the answer given below


I guess you're using the wrong protocol, add the next line to system.properties file (lives in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)
mail.pop3s.ssl.protocols=TLSv1.2

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up
More information:

Configuring JMeter
Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide

